# How to avoid system killing service when application/activity is killed

Tags: android, service, android-activity, system, kill-process

I have an app with one `activity` and one `service`. If I kill the `activity` while the `service` is running it gets killed too. It is very important for me that the service doesn't get killed. How to make that when the system kills (or I kill it by clearing the "Recent apps" list) the `activity` the `service` still remains active until it finishes its job? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you don't destroy the service in onDestroy or somewhere in your activity code?

Comment: Yes I'm sure because I see in logs that the `service` is running and when I clear the "Recent app" list the `service` immediately gets killed and then restarts because I set the `START_STICKY` tag.

Comment: Oh I got you, you were asking about a different thing. But yes, I'm sure about that too. I don't destroy it manually in the `activity`'s code. But, on the other hand, my `activity` doesn't even have an overriden `onDestroy()` method so maybe it is set to kill all the related services by default in that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is very important for me that the service doesn't get killed

Your processes can be killed at any time, for any reason, based on user activity (recent tasks list, a third-party task manager, "Force Stop" in Settings, etc.) or based on OS needs (system RAM is getting low). You cannot prevent this.

You can take some steps to minimize the odds of the OS deciding on its own to terminate your process, such as using `startForeground()` on the service, but this does block the user from doing what the user wants with your app's process.

> I'm displaying a window from that service so if the service stops then the window disappears.

Presumably, the user *wants* your window to disappear if the user is explicitly getting rid of your app via the recent tasks list, a task manager, etc. You are certainly welcome to advise users in your documentation of any negative effects that this will have.

You are also welcome to experiment with having that service be in a separate process. My understanding is that this will not help with the recent-tasks list on Android 4.4, though it might on earlier versions of Android. Whether this helps with third-party task managers probably depends on the manager, and this should not help with "Force Stop" from settings. It also means that you will have to deal with IPC, increased system RAM consumption while your main and service processes are both running, etc.

Comment: Okay, can I start the service in another process so when the user kills my application process my service process still remains untouched?

Comment: @Salivan: Hah, I was just adding an update regarding that -- see the edited answer.

Comment: The window has a close button so the user can get rid of that window by pressing it. This also stops the service. But is there a way to make that the service stays alive after the activity is killed by the user?

Comment: Could you tell me how to start the service in a separate process?

Comment: @Salivan: "But is there a way to make that the service stays alive after the activity is killed by the user?" -- that is addressed in my answer. "Could you tell me how to start the service in a separate process?" -- add an `android:process` attribute to the `<service>` in the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

You can try returning [`START_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) from [`onStartCommand`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) in your Service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: I already did this but this doesn't help at all because I need that the `service` won't stop. I'm displaying a window from that `service` so if the `service` stops then the window disappears. It doesn't make sense to recreate the window. I need it to stay on the screen even if the `activity` is killed so I need to keep that `service` untouched until the window is closed.

Comment: You might try `startForeground`.

Comment: I don't think this could help because I want to avoid the `service` being killed when the user clears "Recent apps" list. Not by the system.

Comment: Is there any chance your problem is related to this issue?
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793

Comment: No, because it is restarting very sucessfully but the problem is that I don't even want it to be killed.

Comment: Then definitely `startForeground` is the way you should go. As written in the documentation: `You can set this flag if killing your service would be disruptive to the user`. Seems like this is what you need.

Comment: But will the service then stay alive if user clears the "Recent apps" list?

Comment: I don't know, give it a try. But like @CommonsWare said in his answer, if you force your window to stay there, then your block the user from doing what he wants to do with your app.

Comment: There is a close button so the user can close that window and stop the service like this.

Comment: In point of the user's view, if the user swipes your app away, that means `exactly` like terminating the app. Meaning he wants your window to go away, else he wouldn't swipe your app away from the recent apps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a bound service? If so, then the system will kill it when the last client activity disconnects (terminates). Here's the blurb from the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html):

> When the last client unbinds from the service, the system destroys the
>   service (unless the service was also started by startService()).

Comment: Not bound service and not system. I want the service to remain alive after the USER clears the "Recent apps" list and kills the activity.